react-beautiful-dnd: How can I prevent elements from shifting around when `isCombineEnabled=true`?
There's an example here, showing exactly what I want but they don't share the full code: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/combining.md
Here's what I've got:
import {
    DragDropContext, Draggable, DraggableProvided, DraggableRubric, DraggableStateSnapshot,
    Droppable,
    DroppableProvided,
    DroppableStateSnapshot,
    DropResult,
    ResponderProvided
} from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import {useCallback} from 'react'

export default function FindDuplicateCustomersPage({customers}: Props) {
    const handleDragEnd = useCallback((result: DropResult, provided: ResponderProvided) => {
        console.log('drag end', result, provided)
        if(result.combine) {
            const {draggableId, combine} = result
            // Handle combining logic here
            console.log(`Combine ${draggableId} with ${combine.draggableId}`)
            // Add your merging logic here
        } else {
            // Handle regular drag end logic here
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <PageHeader>Find Duplicate Customers</PageHeader>
            <ContentWrap>
                <ContentSection title="Merge & Fix" noScroll>
                    {!customers.length ? (
                        <p>No duplicates found.</p>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <p style={{marginBottom: '15px'}}>
                                Drag the duplicate customer ontop of the customer you want to merge the record into. Any
                                bookings for
                                the duplicate customer will be transferred to the customer you drop the record on, and
                                the duplicate
                                customer will be deleted.
                            </p>
                            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
                                <Droppable droppableId="droppable" isCombineEnabled>
                                    {(provided: DroppableProvided, snapshot: DroppableStateSnapshot) => (
                                        <ol className={css.customerList}
                                            ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                                            {customers.map((cust, idx) => (
                                                <Draggable key={cust.id} draggableId={cust.id} index={idx}>
                                                    {(provided: DraggableProvided, snapshot: DraggableStateSnapshot) => (
                                                        <li
                                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                            className={css.customer}
                                                        >
                                                            [{cust.number}] {cust.first_name} {cust.last_name}, {cust.email || '(No Email)'},
                                                            {cust.pri_phone_number || '(No Phone)'},
                                                            Bookings: {cust.booking_count}
                                                            <ExternalLink href={resolveRoute('customers.show', {id: cust.id})}>View</ExternalLink>
                                                        </li>
                                                    )}
                                                </Draggable>
                                            ))}
                                            {provided.placeholder}
                                        </ol>
                                    )}
                                </Droppable>
                            </DragDropContext>
                        </>
                    )}
                </ContentSection>
            </ContentWrap>
        </>
    )
}

But it looks like this:
https://mpen.xyz/share/2024/08/chrome_2024-08-03_16-15-34.webm
You can see the <li>s shifting out of the way, I want them to stay put so that you can drag ontop of another LI to merge them. How do I prevent the shifting around?

You could try to simple increase the item height and catch state change like this and do whatever you want with the list corresponding to it.
...
const handleDragUpdate = useCallback((update: DragUpdate) => {
  console.log('Combined with', update.combine?.draggableId)
}, []);
...
<DragDropContext ... onDragUpdate={handleDragUpdate}>

I cannot find any prop or clear way to prevent this order changing animation in the library source code, though. As they claim it's an abstraction, so you cannot control everything. I would recommend check out a "low-level" https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd library which is actually quite good for such a basic tasks.
